# Upgrading Quark 4 to Quark 7 or 8

Tags: quark

Does anyone have any tips for migrating from Quark 4 to Quark 7 or 8? I'm hoping that its as easy as it looks... but I'm curious if there are any horror stories out in the wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from the Quark website, this is not a very complicated upgrade. There's a small [FAQ](http://8.quark.com/en/quarkupgrade/upgradefaq.html) about it, but it mostly concerns itself with purchasing issues.